# SSRS - When I Select a New Parameter in a Linked Report, the Linked Report Reverts to the Original Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, reporting, ssrs-2019

**Scenario:** Column in main report is set up with the "link to report" action, taking the user to a details report and passing the selected value as a parameter. But once the user is at the details report, I want them to be able to change the parameter value and run the details report for the new value.

**Problem:** What's happening is when I change the value and run the details report, it automatically reverts to the parameter passed by the link action. For example, the user clicks on value AA123 in Main Report. This takes them to Details Report showing details for node AA123. Then while still in Details Report, the user selects value BB456 from a node parameter list so they see details for that node. But instead of the report running for BB456, the node parameter automatically resets to the value passed by the link action, AA123.

**What I Tried:** Under Parameters > Advanced, I tried setting "Refresh data when parameter changes" with each option but always got the same results.  I tried running it with and without default values and always got the same results.